# Element Widths not behaving when browser is zoomed out?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am experiencing frustrating behavior with zooming out my browser. As you can see in this image:

[image]

The editor is supposed to be up next to the scheduler. I transition the editor from a width of 0px to 433px, and transition the scheduler from a width of the viewport, to scheduler-width - 453px, giving a 20px buffer, yet this is still colliding at 75%.... I don't get how? Reducing the scheduler width by 453 and increasing the editor from 0 to 433 should always ensure a 20px buffer between them, but this is not happening when zoomed out... Event if pixel size/count is a bit screwed up due to the zooming, it should still behave correctly as I am telling the scheduler to move over 453px (however they are now defined) to let the scheduler take up 433 of those free pixels.

Is this just odd behavior with zooming in/out of the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use other units, like percents and em, instead of pixels. It should not only solve your issue, but also make your code run better on different-sized displays. Sorry if this is a bit irrelevent.

Comment: So squish the scheduler to, say 75% of the view and extend editor to, say 22% or some such? My one concern is the editor is a form, that I don't want squished to an annoyingly small, which is why I went with a set width for it as opposed to a fluctuating one. I could add in a min-width I suppose.

Comment: While I still don't get what was going on with pixels and zooming in and out... Changing to %s did give me the desired behavior, I just used a max width to prevent the editor from stretching too much on zoomed out browsers.

Comment: Sorry that I haven't been on in a while @TylerDahle, I haven't been on Stack Overflow ever since I answered this question. I'm glad my answer helped get the desired result, although I couldn't help figure out what was wrong. Could there have been a CSS property, like a margin or padding, that was messing something up, maybe a default?

Comment: Nope, inspecting the element showed no padding or margin. I think I did see what was going on. I was using scheduler.element.width(someWidth), But when I did scheduler.element[0].style.width = someWidth + 'px', it worked as expected. I think element.width() was using monitor pixels, while actually setting the css style seemed to use the correct reference pixels for the current zoom/view.